# NSLocalizedString crash

Tags: nslocalizedstring

My app crashes on a `NSLocalizedString` after it has run a few times over it with success.
I have hundreds of other `NSLocalizedStrings` and they all work fine.
I have no clue on why it crashes occasionally.

Help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your console log output when the crash occurs?

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing `@` in the second parameter of the macro.